# Dynamic variable names in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, dynamic

```
@baseball_games = 0
@basketball_games = 0
@football_games = 0

Game.all.each do |game|
  instance_variable_set("@#{game.sport.name.downcase}_games", instance_variable_get("@#{game.sport.name.downcase}_games") + 1)
end
```

Is there a better way to do this, than calling the get method inside the set method? I really am just trying to `+=` the dynamic variable...

Comment: Smells like bad design. How about implementing `[]=`?

Comment: Right, just store them in a hash

Comment: ahhhhhhhh. `games = {basketball: 0, football: 0, baseball: 0}`, then `games[game.sport.name.downcase] += 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon @Santosh's answer, you could do this more generally:

```
@games = Sport.all.map { |sport| [sport.name.to_sym, sport.games.count] }.to_h
```

Comment: Yes. but I suppose the OP wants only the 3 sports he mentioned.

Comment: Nope, I like it. I don't need the count, but it would be nice to auto build that hash if we add more sports down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, without the loop (Assuming the relation is sport has_many games)

```
@games = {
  :baseball => Sport.find_by_name('baseball').games.count,
  :basketball => Sport.find_by_name('basketball').games.count,
  :football => Sport.find_by_name('football').games.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@games = {:baseball => 0, :basketball => 0, :football => 0 }
Game.all.each do |game|
  @games[game.sport.name.downcase.to_sym] = @games[game.sport.name.downcase.to_sym] + 1
end
```